# Passive use of "mete" without the accompanying "out"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, passive-voice, verb-phrases

Given the sentence:

> It is no surprise that his loyal lapdog will be meted a similar fate.

Can the above be considered correct use of the word "mete", and is the overall grammar of the sentence valid?

Comment: To your example, I would find it unusual, and the linked question explains partly why. It's very unusual to encounter *mete* without *out*.

Comment: Thanks @TaliesinMerlim, I already saw that question. It answers why such a usage is unusual, but I wanted to be sure if it was correct or not, since "unusual" doesn't necessarily mean wrong. Still, assuming the sentence used "meted out a similar fate", there's be no question about it being correct, yes?

Comment: The problem with *unusual* uses is not right or wrong, but making a big deal of a little thing, so that  readers stop in their tracks and have to reread the sentence. In poetry, every line can call attention to language. In most narrative, it looks like theatrics that call attention to the writer more than what the writer is expressing. I'm saying I wouldn't want to die on that hill.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Pretty breathtaking spot.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Nicked, tweaked, and databanked for future use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - This one does indeed feel like agreement. Not always sure. We often arrive at similar conclusions for different reasons.